# Передача данных по Bluetooth или же Wi-Fi

Tags: android, c#, wifi, bluetooth

Всем доброго времени суток! Помогите пожалуйста. Мне надо создать программу для проведения викторин по английскому. Для программирования я использую Visual Studio 2013 язык C#. Так вот, нужно сделать так, чтобы к компьютеру могли подключиться телефоны игроков, компьютер будет раздавать вопрос телефонами получать статистику ответов. Вообщем нужно организовать связь между ними. И еще не знаю, как написать приложение под андроид. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: "не знаю, как написать приложение под андроид." - начните с изучения соответствующей платформы, языка, почитайте книжки...

Comment: Раз не знаете "как написать приложение под андроид", но c# это Ваш второй язык, то вперёд к Asp .Net приложению. Смартфоны через браузер авторизуются и готово.

Comment: Смысла учить Android нет, если это не является Вашим основным направлением. Однако, если Вы все же будете под него писать — посмотрите на [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/platform). За неделю может и успеете въехать, но все равно много специфики. Вам однозначно следует консультироваться с существующим разработчиком.